# How to get todays date from date components

Tags: ios, swift

I have time - `08:00 AM` Now I want to assign it with todays date as - `2021-06-11 08:00:00 +0000`

so I can compare `if openTime > Date()`

I am using below code that did not works

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension Formatter {
    static var enUSPOSIX:Locale {
        return Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    }
}
extension Date {
    func stringToDate(string:String, format: String, timeZone:TimeZone = .current) -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Formatter.enUSPOSIX
        dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.date(from: string)
    }
}
let openTime = Date().stringToDate(string: "08:00 AM", format: "hh:mm a")!
print(openTime)
print("Date----", Date())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify a dates hour, minute and second properties, you can use following:

```
let openTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())
```